# How to resolve clashing definitions of \comment in comment.sty and changes.sty without affecting either's interface?

Tags: macros, environments, package-writing, comments, changes

I'm writing a package that uses both [changes](https://ctan.org/pkg/changes?lang=en) (v3.1.2) and [comment](https://ctan.org/pkg/comment?lang=en) (v3.8), and I'd like to expose their functionality to consumers of my package without having to modify either one's interface.

The problem is that both `changes.sty` and `comment.sty` define `\comment`. Hence

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}\end{document}
```

throws the error

> Command \comment already defined.

I understand this can be fixed using [savesym](https://ctan.org/pkg/savesym) by (essentially) modifying `changes.sty`'s interface, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym}

\usepackage{changes}
\savesymbol{comment} % rename \comment -> \origcomment
\usepackage{comment}

\begin{document}
\origcomment{pdf comment using 'changes.sty'}
\begin{comment}
code comment using 'comment.sty'
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, `comment.sty` provides `\excludecomment` for defining custom comment environments, e.g.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{savesym}

\usepackage{comment}
\savesymbol{comment}
\excludecomment{mycomment}
\usepackage{changes}

\begin{document}
\comment{pdf comment using 'changes.sty'}
\begin{mycomment}
code comment using 'comment.sty'
\end{mycomment}
\end{document}
```

but `changes.sty` breaks the default `comment` environment.

Is it possible to build a layer in my package which mediates between `changes.sty`'s `\comment` command and `comment.sty`'s `comment` environment? The aim is to expose the original interface of each to a consumer of my package.

---

The two clashing definitions are as follows:

```latex
% changes.sty line 791
\newcommand{\comment}[2][\@empty]{%
\setkeys{Changes@comment}{#1}%
\Changes@output%
{comment}%
{\Changes@comment@id}%
{}%
{}%
{#2}%
{\changescommentname}%
{#2}%
}
```

```latex
% comment.sty line 241
\def\excludecomment
 #1{\message{Excluding comment '#1'}%
    \csarg\def{#1}{\endgroup \message{Excluding '#1' comment.}%
        \begingroup
           \DefaultCutFileName \def\ProcessCutFile{}%
           \def\ThisComment####1{}\ProcessComment{#1}}%
    \csarg\def{After#1Comment}{\CloseAndInputCutFile \endgroup}
    \CommentEndDef{#1}}
% ...
% line 292
\excludecomment{comment}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can via `\let` save both the `\comment`-macro which underlies the `comment`-environment of the comment package and the `\comment`-macro which comes with the changes-package.

Then you can define your own `\comment`-macro which "looks" at the definition of `\@currenvir`.

If `\@currenvir` = comment, then executing `\comment` imples calling the macro which underlies the comment-environment.
Otherwise executing `\comment` implies calling the macro which comes from the changes-package.

Be aware that with the following example I said `\includecomment{comment}` so that the content of comment-environments results in visual output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\UD@CommentName{comment}%
\newcommand\UDsavedcommentenvironment{}%
\newcommand\UDsavedcommentmacro{}%
\usepackage{changes}[2019/01/26 v3.1.2]
\let\UDsavedcommentmacro=\comment
\let\comment=\relax
\usepackage{comment}%[2016/07/16 v3.8]
\includecomment{comment}%
%\excludecomment{comment}%
\let\UDsavedcommentenvironment=\comment
\let\comment=\relax
\newcommand\comment{%
  \ifx\@currenvir\UD@CommentName
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\UDsavedcommentenvironment}{\UDsavedcommentmacro}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null
\comment{A pdf comment using `changes.sty'.}%
\begin{comment}
A code comment using `comment.sty'.
\end{comment}
\comment{Another pdf comment using `changes.sty'.}%
\begin{comment}
Another code comment using `comment.sty'.
\end{comment}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has all the basic elements I was looking for. Just one question: why the first 3 `\newcommand`s? Is it to ensure you're not clobbering previously-defined commands, a stylistic choice, or something deeper?

Comment: You are right: The `\newcommand` for `\UD@CommentName` just defines the macro as it is needed.The second and the third  `\newcommand`  are to ensure that an error is raised in case the macros `\UDsavedcommentenvironment` and `\UDsavedcommentmacro`  are already defined. As the likelihood for a macro whose name starts with `\UD...` already being defined is low and as one could as well use `\@ifdefinable` for testing, you can take this for a "stylistic" thing. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Since v4.0.0 the `changes` package allows for initializing with the `commandnameprefix` option like so

```
\usepackage[commandnameprefix=always]{changes}
```

This changes the commands:

- \added → \chadded
- \deleted → \chdeleted
- \replaced → \chreplaced
- \highlight → \chhighlight
- \comment → \chcomment

The new commands are unlikely to collide with existing ones.

Most typically commands like `comment` or `highlight` result in conflicts, and one thus might be interested (and able) to preserve the commands `added`, `replaced` and `deleted` in the their original form. This can be achieved by:

```
\usepackage[commandnameprefix=ifneeded]{changes}
```

Which only overwrites the necessary commands. Note that this can result in a mixture of `ch`-prefixed and normal commands.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution based on @Ulrich Diez's answer, the main differences being the use of `\@undefined` instead of `\relax` and a simpler if-then-else statement:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\usepackage{comment}
\let\wfs@comment@comment\comment
\let\comment\@undefined

\usepackage{changes}
\let\wfs@changes@comment\comment
\let\comment\@undefined

\newcommand\comment{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@currenvir}{comment}}
    {\wfs@comment@comment}
    {\wfs@changes@comment}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\comment{pdf comment 1}
\begin{comment}
code comment 1
\end{comment}
\comment{pdf comment 2}
\begin{comment}
code comment 2
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Then I copied the preamble into my package, removed `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, and replaced `\usepackage` -> `\RequirePackage`.

Answer (score -1):

Despite I put `\usepackage[commandnameprefix=always]{changes}` on the preamble following @gijswijs's advice, I still receive error for :

> LaTeX Error: Command \comment already defined.
> LaTeX Error: Command \highlight already defined.

Could you please tell me what is wrong with my preamble below?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyc,natbib,citestyle=authoryear, style=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage[commandnameprefix=always]{changes}

\DeclareSortingScheme{nyc}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{\citeorder}
}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage[indent=0cm]{parskip}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=5cm]{geometry}

% Table                                       
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[font=normalsize,labelfont={bf}]{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{easyReview}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{authblk}
%\newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: @n61 If you have a question, please use the "Ask Question" button at the top right. The space here, is reserved for solutions, not follow-up questions.